# How to implement Levenshtein Distance Algorithm in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, levenshtein-distance

I've a text file which contains the information about the sender and messages and the format is sender,messages. I want to use **Levenshtein Distance Algorithm** with threshold of 70% and want to store the similar messages to the Map. In the Map, My key is `String` and value is `List[String]`

For example my requirement is: If my messages are abc, bcd, cdf.

**step1:** First I should add the message 'abc' to the List. `map.put("Group1",abc.toList)`

**step2:** Next, I should compare the 'bcd'(2nd message) with 'abc'(1st message). If they meets the threshold of 70% then I should add the 'bcd' to List. Now, 'abc' and 'bcd' are added under the same key called 'Group1'.

**step3:** Now, I should get all the elements from Map. Currently G1 only with 2 values(abc,bcd), next compare the current message 'cdf' with 'abc' or 'bcd' (As 'abc' and 'bcd' is similar comparing with any one of them would be enough)

**step4:** If did not meet the threshold, I should create a new key "Group2" and add that message to the List and so on.

The 70% threshold means, For example:

**message1:** Dear customer! your mobile number 9032412236 has been successfully recharged with INR 500.00

**message2:** Dear customer! your mobile number 7999610201 has been successfully recharged with INR 500.00

Here, the Levenshtein Distance between these two is 8. We can check this here: https://planetcalc.com/1721/

8 edits needs to be done, 8 characters did not match out of (message1.length+message2.length)/2

If I assume the first message is of 100 characters and second message is of 100 characters then the average length is 100, out of 100, 8 characters did not match which means the accuracy level of this is 92%, so here, I should keep threshold 70%.

If Levenshtein distance matching at least 70%, then take them as similar.

I'm using the below library:

```
libraryDependencies += "info.debatty" % "java-string-similarity" % "2.0.0"
```

My code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object Demo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val inputFile = "D:\\MyData.txt"
    val data = sc.textFile(inputFile)
    val data2 = data.map(line => {
      val arr = line.split(","); (arr(0), arr(1))
    })
    val grpData = data2.groupByKey()
    val myMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, List[String]]
    for (values <- grpData.values.collect) {
      val list = ListBuffer[String]()
      for (value <- values) {
        println(values)
        if (myMap.isEmpty) {
          list += value
          myMap.put("G1", list.toList)
        } else {
          val currentMsg = value
          val valuePartOnly = myMap.valuesIterator.toString()
          for (messages <- valuePartOnly) {
            def levenshteinDistance(currentMsg: String, messages: String) = {
              ???//TODO: Implement distance
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After the else part, I'm not sure how do I start with this algorithm.

I do not have any output sample. So, I've explained it step by step.

Please check from step1 to step4.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you already tried anything? Any issues you faced so far? Do you have maybe any code snippet which you tried? Thanks

Comment: The sample input is an image so it can't be copy-pasted into our work environment. Without a sample of desired output how would we know if our suggested answers are correct? If my solution is not correct you should show me where it produces bad results.

Comment: As I'm very new to stack overflow I don't know how upload my input file here, I'm sorry for that, I've been explained what needs to be done, but not given any output sample.

Comment: Okay, I will check and update you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really certain about next code I did not tried it, but I hope it demonstrates the idea:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object Demo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
    val distance: Levenshtein = new Levenshtein(); //Create object for calculation distance
    
    def levenshteinDistance(left: String, right: String): Double = {
      // I'm not really certain about this, how you would like to calculate relative distance?
      // Relatevly to string with max size, min size, left or right?
      l.distance(left, right) / Math.max(left.size, right.size) 
    }
    
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val inputFile = "D:\\MyData.txt"
    val data = sc.textFile(inputFile)
    val data2 = data.map(line => {
      val arr = line.split(","); (arr(0), arr(1))
    })
    val grpData = data2.groupByKey()
    val messages = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, List[String]]
    var group = 1
    for (values <- grpData.values.collect) {
      val list = ListBuffer[String]()
      for (value <- values) {
        println(values)
        if (messages.isEmpty) {
          list += value
          messages.put("G$group", list.toList)
        } else {
          val currentMsg = value
          val group = messages.values.find {
            case(key, messages) => messages.forall(message => levenshteinDistance(currentMsg, message) <= 0.7)
          }._1.getOrElse {
            group += 1
            "G$group"
          }
          val groupMessages = messages.getOrEse(group, ListBuffer.empty[String])
          groupMessages.append(currentMsg)
          messages.put(currentMsg, groupMessages)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```